# How to intercept ivy dependency names in an ant script

Tags: ant, ivy

In my ant script, I want to intercept ivy dependency names so that I can use those names inside the script.  The reason is that the dependency names are not always known ahead of time.  The ivy.xml file gets dynamically updated with dependencies of the users's choosing and the build script has to use those.

Is there a way to intercept ivy dependency names using ivy:retrieve?

Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify your problem with an example? retrieve will download all dependencies to a defined directory. You can use the dependencies in that directory for whatever needs to be done in your script (with filesets and so on). Why would you need to intercept here?

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, rohitsan probably wants to modify the dependencies, not just access the information from ivy.xml.

Comment: it was a duplicate.  you just use [module].

Answer (score 0):

One of our projects is using a workaround, where you define `ivy-tokens.xml`, which contains tokens for the items not known in advance, and then the build script copies this file to `ivy.xml`, replaces the tokens and only then starts the Ivy related tasks.